# Reading a text file into a data structure in C

Tags: c, data-structures, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C, reading from file into structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280523/c-reading-from-file-into-structure)

I need to read a large text file and then fill a data structure for a mailing list.

The data structure is as follows:

```
typedef struct mentry {
    char *surname;
    int house_number;
    char *postcode;
    char *full_address;
} MEntry;
```

and the text file format is:

```
Bloggs, Joe  
1 Street Name, City  
M53 3JK  
Surname, Firstname  
University of Nowhere, City  
G44 3GB
```

etc.

And my constructor for the data struct:

```
/* me_get returns the next file entry, or NULL if end of file*/
MEntry *me_get(FILE *fd);
```

Which returns a pointer to an MEntry structure containing the mailing list entry.

So far I have only managed to read the file in line by line.

```
#define MAXLINE 1024

int main(){
    char line[MAXLINE];
    FILE *fp = fopen("S.txt","r");

    while(fgets(line,MAXLINE,fp))
        {
        printf("%s %d",line,linecount);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

My main problem at the moment is that I don't know how to split my lines so that I can fill my data structure correctly. I am wondering if using fgetc to read a character in a time would be easier than reading in a whole line and then trying to split it?

Comment: you probably want to use `regex` and/or a scripting language like `Python`.

Comment: This is a very common problem, so I tried coping your title into the search and it spit out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014045 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556629 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280523 and so on. Most of these probably came up when you were entering the title in the "ask a question" page, so why didn't you look at them?

Comment: @Ken Only if he (1) knows how to interface the language with c (no guarantees as this is a beginner's question) and (2) wants the whole thing to be horribly fragile.

Comment: @dmckee i think that if you want to do this in C your best bet are the regex, we are talking about a language that doesn't even make a real distinction between integers and chars, and does not have the notion of string as primitive type. I don't think that a parser like this can be something other than _fragile_ if done in C.

Comment: I did have a look at the other questions, but the format of their text file is consistent and doesn't involve discarding/splitting of the data.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should use **strtok**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char str[] ="Elizarraras, Salvador, UG";
    char *token = NULL;
    int n_tokens = 0;

    printf ("Get tokens from string \"%s\"\n",str);
    printf("%s\n", "*********************************************");

   // Split the string into tokens delimited by spaces and commas
   token = strtok (str," ,");
   while (token != NULL)
   {
       printf("%s\n", token);
       // Different call
       token = strtok (NULL, " ,");
       n_tokens++;
   }

  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Get tokens from string "Elizarraras, Salvador, UG"

*********************************************
Elizarraras

Salvador

UG
```

There is an interesting article about this topic, [Finding Tokens in a String](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the second address does not have any `house_number`.

This means that you cannot rely on the data format to blindly read the file.

You have no choice but to read the data and then parse it.

Other issues could happen if an address had 2 lines of text before the `postcode` is specified.

You are the only one to know how reliable is your input file and therefore what rules must be applied to parse it without errors.

Regarding the method, I would read the file line by line and interpret it on-the-fly, by parsing each line of text, until the `postcode` is found for each record (as this seems to be your end-of-record marker).

Parsing means looking at the `line[]` characters and classifying the data as you read it (i.e.: a comma is the delimiter for first / last names, a street number is a number, a postcode follow a certain format, etc.).

This will require a bit of work, but this is doable. By taste, you understood that I would not venture in the RegEx area (while C has a dedicated runtime library).

Goog luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// It is easyer for the memory allocator to have all in the struct
// It is a bit more wasteful on memory though if you set those too large
#define MAX_SURNAME_LENGTH 32
#define MAX_POSTCODE_LENGTH 32
#define MAX_FULL_ADDRESS_LENGTH (256 - MAX_SURNAME_LENGTH - MAX_POSTCODE_LENGTH - sizeof(int))

typedef struct mentry {
    char surname[MAX_SURNAME_LENGTH];
    char postcode[MAX_POSTCODE_LENGTH];
    int house_number;
    char full_address[MAX_FULL_ADDRESS_LENGTH];
} MEntry;

MEntry *me_get(FILE *fp) {
    MEntry *mentry = calloc(sizeof(MEntry), 1);

    // get name
    char * name = fgets(mentry->surname, sizeof(mentry->surname), fp);
    if (!name) { //failure
        free(mentry);
        return NULL;
    }

    char * comma = strchr(name, ','); // find the first comma appearance
    if (comma) *comma = '\0'; // If name has a comma in it, terminate the string there

    char * address = fgets(mentry->full_address, sizeof(mentry->full_address), fp);
    if (!address) { //failure
        free(mentry);
        return NULL;
    }

    char * restaddress;
    int housenumber = strtol(address, &restaddress, 10);

    if (restaddress != address) // there was a valid number at the start of address
        mentry->house_number = housenumber;

    char * postcode = fgets(mentry->postcode, sizeof(mentry->postcode), fp);
    if (!postcode) { //failure
        free(mentry);
        return NULL;
    }

    return mentry;
}

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("S.txt","r");

    MEntry *mentry;
    while ((mentry = me_get(fp))) {
        // do something useful with mentry
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```